# Driving to the DVLA with an international license alone for the practical test

Tags: united-kingdom

My current license cannot be changed to the UK's, so I am in the process of obtaining a UK driver's license. I have the learner license and have passed the theory test.

I have a valid international driver's license and I have been in the UK for 5 months.

Non-international license holders must be accompanied by a driving instructor or an adult with the driving license to go to the UK driving test location to take the driving test.

Do international drivers who are still allowed to drive in the UK legally with the home country's driving license have to bring someone else to the UK driving test too?

Can I just drive to the test center with a rental car alone?. If I don't pass, can I still drive back with my home country's driving license?

Comment: What did the DVLA say when you [contacted them](https://www.gov.uk/contact-the-dvla/y/driving-licences-and-applications)?

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to use your old driving license for 1 year after entering the United Kingdom. This also means you can drive as a learner without L plates until your old license is valid and go to the test centre using your own car with no one accompanying you. You will need to fit your car with L plates for the duration of the test though, and make sure it is insured properly for you to drive it.

However you are only allowed to use a hire car if it's fitted with dual controls: https://www.gov.uk/driving-test/using-your-own-car

> **Hire cars**
>
> You can take your test in a hire car if it’s fitted with dual controls and meets all the other rules.

[There are definitely companies](https://www.arnoldclarkrental.com/dual-control-hire) specializing in renting dual control cars, however they might refuse to rent if you are alone and not accompanied by someone having a full UK license:

> You must be 17 years old or over, possess a clean, current UK provisional licence and be accompanied at all times by a qualified driver, who is 23 years old or over.

Generally you don't need anyone else to be present during the test, as it will be only between you and the examiner. (This is true even if you don't have a valid, but not-exchangeable license)

[This DVSA examiner claims your case happens fairly often](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnerDriverUK/comments/13o0zgs/comment/jl240jg/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> DVSA Examiner (Verified by admin)
>
> See it plenty of times - international licence holder rocks up to the test centre, puts on L plates, fails (or passes), removes L plates and drives away themselves again.
>
> It's a rather strange loophole - if they've failed the driving test they're potentially not safe to be on the roads yet can drive away as if nothing has happened.

Comment: He is going to use his own car. So it's not really a problem.

About the hire car. I wonder if that's even enforced. If no labels are visible, how do you is a hire car or not?

Answer (score -1):

When we went for my wife's driving test, no one questioned me. They didn't take my details. I was like a shadow for them.

From my point of view. It seems like as far they see a car with an aux mirror + L plates. No body cares.

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic. Are you saying you accompanied your learner-driver wife but *you* did not have a valid licence? Why would you expect the driving test centre ask to see *your* credentials if you were not due to take a test?

Comment: @Traveller I have a valid license but that's not my point. My point is, the driving examiner doesn't care how the learner got there.